# Shallow copy for one dimensional list

Tags: python-3.6

While reading [shallow copy](https://docs.python.org/3/library/copy.html). It says that copy.copy(x) create shallow copy. But  I don't see shallow copy behavior in case of the single dimensional list.

Example:

```
>> new = [1,2,3,4,5,6]
>> original = copy.copy(new)
>> new
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
>> original
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
>> id(new)
65022912
>> id(original)
65022512
>> new[2]=13
>> new
[1, 2, 13, 4, 5, 6]
>> original
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
```

So here I assume updating "new" list should update "original" list but it is not happening.

In the case of the multidimensional list, the shallow copy is working properly.

Example:

```
>> parent_list = [1, 2, [3,4], [5,6]]
>> child_list = copy.copy(parent_list)
>> parent_list[2][1] = "Python"
>> parent_list
[1, 2, [3, 'Python'], [5, 6]]
>> child_list
[1, 2, [3, 'Python'], [5, 6]]
```

Please guide me, why the shallow copy is not working in case of a one-dimensional list.

Thanks.

Comment: Shallow copies would create copies of the primary lists, and your results are expected. Because each element is primitive type. All primitive types are copied by value, and not reference. Shallow copies duplicate the references to an object.

Comment: What you seem to want isn't a shallow copy at all, just aliasing. `new = original` would have the behavior you seem to expect; it shallow copies in the sense of copying the reference to the underlying `list`.

Comment: While I look for a good duplicate target, here is a very good article that can help you understand this topic: https://nedbatchelder.com/text/names.html

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Changing list elements in shallow copy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48178836/changing-list-elements-in-shallow-copy)

Comment: @PatrickHaugh: Not exactly a duplicate; the OP seems to want a shallow copy that copies even less, and is surprised it copies as much as it does (the OP here seems to want plain aliasing, no copying at all). Your duplicate is about shallow copying vs. deep copying.

Comment: @ShadowRanger when we say new = original it is not shallow copy at all. It is hard copying. Python has given copy.copy(x) for the shallow copy. Above in my question, I also have shared shallow copy reference.

Comment: @kanishk: "Hard copying" is not a term I've ever heard of. `new = original` has the behavior you seem to expect from shallow copying, but it is not shallow copying, it's aliasing. The only way that `new[2] = 13` would change `original` is if you'd used `new = original`; using `new = copy.copy(original)` (or equivalently, `new = original[:]`), you've shallow copied the `list` itself, with both copies referencing the same objects independently, but `new[2] = 13` rebinds the references at `new[2]` to a different object.

Answer (score 0):

There are actually 3 "Levels" to what you want.

1) Create a new reference to the same list. This aliasing is a trivial operation and would look like "original = new" or something like that.  original[1] =x will update new[1];  This is the equivalent of copying a pointer in a pointer based language.

```
original = new
original[1] = x
new[1] will now be updated to x
```

This should be obvious but for completeness, If you follow the above with:

```
new = other
original is NOT affected at all.
```

2) Create a "Copy" of the list.  It will allocate a new area and copy elements of the list.  This is a "Shallow" copy.  The children copied will be references, but the list itself will contain copies.  original[1] =x will NOT update new[1], but original[1].childValue =x will update new[1].childValue

```
original = shallow copy of new
original[1].value = x
new[1].value WILL change to x
original[1] = y
new[1] will NOT be affected
```

3) Create a deep copy of the list.  This will allocate a new area and shallow copy the list, but then will recurse and copy each child referenced in the list.  No updates to original will modify new, or vice-a-versa.

```
original = deep copy of new
original[1].value = x
new[1].value will NOT be affected
original[1] = y
new[1] will NOT be affected
```

A shallow copy of a list is not usually what you want because your list is left in a hybrid state with some members referencing other lists and some not which will lead to unpredictable behavior, but it may be necessary if your tree is fairly deep and/or you never modify the child nodes.

Comment: For future reference, [#1 is usually referred to a "aliasing"](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/classes.html#a-word-about-names-and-objects), e.g. `new = original` is aliasing `new` to the same value as `original`.

Answer (score 0):

original[1].value = x is giving error :AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'values'
After writing the below code:

```
new = [1,2,3,4,5,6]
original = new.copy()
original[1] = 10
print("new:",new , "\n " ,"original:", original)
the output I am getting is :
new: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6] 
 original: [1, 10, 3, 4, 5, 6]
```

changes done in the original are not getting reflected for a new list where an index is the same or a shallow copy